# How can I stop a DHCP server from assigning an IP to a particular user?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, dhcp

How can I stop a Windows 2003 DHCP server from assigning an IP to a particular user?

Comment: I think that you might need to learn some basics about DHCP and TCP/IP in general.

Answer (score 1):

DHCP leases are not given out on a per user account basis, only per computer. The only way I know of of not giving a computer a DHCP lease would be to give the computer a static IP address outside of the DHCP scope

Comment: Or configure reservations for all addresses in the scope.

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses are assigned to network interfaces on computer, not to users. To answer your question as you've presented it: you can't.

If you'd like for a specific *computer* to not be assigned an IP address by a DHCP server, you can accomplish this a few ways. You can put the computer on a vlan/subnet that doesn't have a DHCP server on it. Don't enable DHCP Relay for that subnet and you're fine. Or, just assign a static IP address to the interface in question.